# Solving first order non-linear ODE with logarithm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, nonlinear-dynamics

I want to solve for $t \in \mathbb{R}, u'(t)=-u(t)\ln \lvert u(t) \rvert$.

I defined two cases: $\mathbb{R^*_+}$ and $\mathbb{R^*_-}$.

For $\mathbb{R^*_+}$:

$$\frac{du}{u}=-\ln(u(t))dt$$

And by integrating, it follows that:

$$\ln\lvert u \rvert = -u\ln(u) + u$$

But I'm stuck here, I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{du}{u}=-\ln(u(t))dt$$
You cannot integrate $\int-\ln(u(t))dt$ directly.

The mistake is : You integrate $\quad \int-\ln(u(t))du= -u\ln(u)+u\quad$ but this is not $\quad \int -\ln(u(t))dt$.

Back to the original ODE :
$$\frac{du}{dt}=u\ln(u)$$
This is a separable ODE thus
$$\frac{du}{u\ln(u)}=dt$$
$$\int\frac{du}{u\ln(u)}=\int dt$$
$$\ln(\ln(u))=t+c$$
$$u=\exp(\exp(t+c))$$

Answer (score 3):

The above solution is absolutely correct.  A slightly quicker way is to substitute
$$
u(t) = e^{f(t)}
$$
producing the differential equation:
$$
f'=-f
$$
eventually leading to the same answer.